# keep pwa running in background

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

i have a pwa created with `angular 9` , the application is for trading, so data, changes
almost every second , my users can create statements and when their statements become
true my application will notice them by sending notification , i also have a service
worker installed and activated , everything is good in desktop and also in mobile
but when mobile screen turns off or pwa minimized , pwa stop working and notifications
are not send anymore , i tried `background-sync` and `periodic-background-sync`, but wasnt
helpful

can anyone give me a clue what i have to do ?

this is my **serviceWorker**

```
async function grantPeriodic(){
  const status = await navigator.permissions.query({
    name: 'periodic-background-sync',
  });
  if (status.state === 'granted') {
    console.log("granted");
  } else {
  }
}

async function periodicSyncFunc(){
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  if ('periodicSync' in registration) {
    try {
      console.log("synced");
      await registration.periodicSync.register('content-sync', {
        minInterval:  10000,
      });
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }
}

self.addEventListener('periodicsync', (event) => {
  if (event.tag === 'content-sync') {
    event.waitUntil(
      periodicSyncFunc()
    );
  }
});

grantPeriodic() ;
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238598/pwa-push-notification-not-showing-when-app-is-not-running

Comment: You can use web push notifications. But it is not supported in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get to run a PWA app in the background. The periodic sync route seems to be a dead end, since it only allows a service worker to run once every 24 hours. See https://github.com/WICG/background-sync/issues/169#issuecomment-563942794

You mininterval of 10 seconds would not be adhered to. I'm trying to create some kind of geofenching app